# gimp 2.10 not updating library? from 2.8

Tags: upgrade, application

I have gimp 2.10.18 issues that do not update the installation in the libraries because I am trying to install plugins and do a course but when I go to the files to add them, there are none listed and it still says gimp 2.8 and not 2.10.18 in the hidden files area. after pasting and making executable with permissions etc, no change in 2.10 operation.  when both are uninstalled and then autoremove/autoclean is used, the files are still installed?

How can I solve this issue?

linux mint 19, up to date, as im in a linux forum. HP amd a8- r5, 8gb ram

Comment: Please start with the basics: which operating system (name and version) are you using? From your terminology, I would guess you're probably using some version of MacOS? And can you give a link to the instructions you're following, or otherwise describe **in exact detail** what you have been doing?

Comment: linux mint 19, up to date, as im in a linux forum. HP amd a8- r5, 8gb ram,

Comment: Please edit your original question to add any extra information, as these comments will not be permanent. What is the output if you run `sudo apt list --installed | grep gimp`? If the output includes no names and versions of gimp packages, or only lists gimp 2.8, what is the exact procedure you used to install/update to version 2.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the PPA for 2.10.18 is currently not in the package manager and is only available for 2.10.14, so all plug-ins do not show up in Gimp 2.10.18 at present for me.

I installed all PPA support in the package manager for 2.10.14 and all plug-ins with it, and it seems to work fine, and Gimp 2.8 no longer shows up  as the software manager is updated to 2.10.14 also.

Will have to wait for 2.10.18 PPA to be updated on linux mint network as far as I can know.